# Hovering on JButtons in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mousehover

Now I have multiple buttons on my JFrame, when the button is hovered, the button's color will be changed and after my cursor leaves the button, the button's color will change back to it's original color. As now I'm applying this code to all my buttons:

```
private void btn1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
        btn1.setBackground(new Color(236, 252, 250));
    }                                      

    private void btn1MouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        btn1.setBackground(new Color(241, 241, 241));
    }
```

Which makes me feel there's little bit of redundancy, is it possible to write a shorter code that the buttons will check itself whether it's hovered and will change color but change back to original color after unhovered?

Comment: There's nothing redundant in the code you've posted. Another way to achieve this is to use custom icons for normal button state and hover state, or to add a ChangeListener to the button's model to check the rollover state, but I don't know if this is more efficient code for you or not.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking to create a factory method for creation of your buttons, and this way place pertinent code in this one single method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Alright, thanks for the recommendations, I'll check it out! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which makes me feel there's little bit of redundancy

You can easily create a generic listener to be shared by all buttons:

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter()
{
    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
    {            
        Component c = evt.getComponent();                   
        c.setBackground(new Color(236, 252, 250));
    }                                      

    public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
    {                                      
        Component c = evt.getComponent();
        c.setBackground(new Color(241, 241, 241));
    }  
}
```

Then in your code you can add the listener to the button:

```
btn1.addMouseListener( ml );
btn2.addMouseListener( ml );
```